# Upcasting without retaining reference to derived type

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, polymorphism, entity

I have a class called `Resource`, this is inherited by a class called `ResourceMeta`

I need to upcast `ResourceMeta` to `Resource` without it still thinking it is a type of `ResourceMeta`.

When I try to save my object using entity framework, it will complain about mappings not existing, rightly so because it will be trying to save `ResourceMeta` rather than `Resource`.

I've tried `(Resource)resourceMeta` however this still retains the type of `ResourceMeta` just limits the properties available to `Resource`.

Comment: Assuming Resource is a superclass of ResourceMeta (class ResourceMeta: Resource), casting from ResourceMeta to Resource would be upcasting, not downcasting.

Answer (score 3):

That is not possible, you can't change the actual type of an object.

To get a Resource object from a ResourceMeta object, you have to create a new Resource object using the data from the ResourceMeta object.

Comment: @Shahin: Yes, it's possible to hack an object to think that it's a different object, but this can easily blow up. For example, the garbage collector occationally moves object in memory, and if it moves an object thinking that it is a different type, it could corrupt other objects, or the memory management itself.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible in simple words , you need to create a new instance of Resource and then return

Answer (score 0):

Is inheritance the correct representation of the association between `ResourceMeta` and `Resource` instances. If not, you could favor composition instead of inheritance and in this way when you want to save the resource instance you could just do `resourceMetaInstance.Resource`.